# r programming replace a string with another string

Tags: r

supplose if I have a string such as

### Input:

```
myString <- "myFunc(apple,mango,orange,banana)"
```

I want to make a regex such that I produce the following

### Output:

```
myString <- "myFunc(input$apple,input$mango,input$orange,input$banana)"
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe this will work instead: `myString <- paste0("with(input, ", "myFunc(input1,input2,input3,input4)")`  If not what are the rule to govern insertion?  Always after a `(` or `,`?

Comment: after a "(" for the first one and "," thereafter

Comment: how did you arrive at this problem, what are you _really_ trying to do

Comment: @rawr excellent question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myString <- "myFunc(apple,mango,orange,banana)"

gsub("(\\(|,)", "\\1input$", myString)

## "myFunc(input$apple,input$mango,input$orange,input$banana)"
```